# display the REST API result in textview in Swift doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, textview, rest

I am trying to develop a function to connect and read from a REST API, then display the returning json in a textview, with following code :

```
func restapiRead()
{
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        print(response!)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            print(json)
            self.mytv.text = "\(json as! [[String: AnyObject]])" //> code line 1
            self.mytv.text = "\(json as! NSArray)" //> code line 2
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    })

    task.resume()    
  }
```

Actually all code above works without any error, but then I use codeline1 or codeline2 to copy the result in textview, it warns with a "warning" message as :

Cast from '[String : AnyObject]' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always fails

If I run ignore the warning and run, I get the following error at codeline1 (and 2 as well):

Thread 6: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

How can I copy the result as raw json in the textview?

Thank you

Comment: You can’t just dump a dictionary into a text view, you should  the values you want to use first and if necessary convert them to String objects. Also, you are trying to update a UI component from a background thread, use `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` for the update

Comment: thank you for response, but just wish to know: is there any way to dump to see as raw it is? for example; I can get the whole json  result (as raw) when it call print(json), or is there a component that I can dump it as raw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should json convert to string for use textView .

```
   json.description
```

tested 100% ok

code change to :

```
  func restapiRead()
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            print(response!)
            do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.mytv.text =  json.description
                   }
                }
         
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        })

        task.resume()
      }
```